# Has anyone used material-ui with browsersync?

Tags: material-ui, browser-sync

Has anyone used material-ui with browsersync?

I have recently started using https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate to start react projects. This uses `react-mdl` (React Material Design Light) and BrowserSync out of the box.

I tried switching to `material-ui` but I don't think that browsersync is successfully communicating the `touchTap`event across browser instances.

As far as I can tell, this is expected behavior, but I am curious if there are any workarounds.

- https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/22

Comment: I've personally never had any issues with it. It could be that you should inject it somewhere else in your code and it is somehow being skipped/ignored.

Could you provide examples of your code so that the community can better assist you?

Comment: Absolutely, I'll setup a skeleton repo in github that reproduces the issue.